# Google BigQuery/Cloud Storage Invalid source uri prefix error

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

We are currently observing a bug (at least we hope it's nothing on our end) that prevents BigQuery from accessing data stored in Google Cloud Storage (external table) using Hive Partitioning URI Prefix.

Our setup was working for months without any change, and since yesterday we are just getting an error

> Error code 3 : Invalid value: Invalid source uri prefix:...

when our scheduled query tries to run.

We can access the data without partitioning but are running in an error with Hive Partitioning URI Prefix.

Is anyone else seeing such behavior?

Cheers

Comment: Haven't observed this, but it may be a case of a file/object that was recently added to the GCS bucket that violates the defined pattern of the hive partitioning scheme?

Comment: Are you able to create a new external table accessing that bucket, specifying the partition?

Comment: it seems like you need to create a first folder in the bucket and then create the path with your hive partition fields (e.g.: `gs://bucket-name/table-name/{partition_field1:STRING}/{partition_field2:STRING}` )

Comment: Yep we are experiencing this ... it's affecting ~10% of our batch transactions atm and AFAIK is not coming from changes to the projects or source data from our end

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK This problem is consistently occurring on and only on partitioned `EXTERNAL TABLE`s that have the following field/value definition (`bigquery.v2.table`) `objectsPrefix: /*`.

For our organisation this definition occurs when there is no objects prefix and the partitionsPrefix is available at the root of the bucket. For historical reasons, this impacts about 10 of ~100 EXTERNAL TABLE definitions. And as a consequence, is fairly easy to remediate manually.

Our temporary solution it to move the source data into a subdirectory (prefix) in the bucket and updating the table definitions accordingly.

This has worked so far. But we are obviously raising a support ticket with Google AND hoping to identify a real fix or the real problem as this doesn't **feel** like the **right** course of action.

All the same, I wanted to add it to this chat in case it helps anyone else temporarily.  And to track this chat in case a longer term solution is found.

Comment: that could have been a real pain... question: Why did you decide, for the 90 "other" buckets, to put a prefix? AFAIK that was not on the documentation (It seems it was updated  on the 16th)

Comment: The other buckets are simply prefixed because the jobs that emitted the original data were just configured to do so. It's simply been luck.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with Google BigQuery has been resolved for all affected projects as of Tuesday, 2021-07-20 08:20 US/Pacific.